# Finding the order of an element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $N$ ≤ ($\mathbb Z^2$, +) be the subgroup given by $\;N =\bigl\{ (x, y)  ∈  \mathbb Z^2\mid  3x+5y ≡ 0  \pmod{30}\bigr\}$ .
>
> In the quotient $G = \mathbb Z^2/N$, find the order of the element $(1, 1) + N$.

I've came across the problem and I don't know where and how to start. Please any help?

Comment: Try calculating some multiples of the given element in the given group. Can you find such a multiple that is the identity of the group (that is, one that lies in $N$)? If so, that gives you an upper bound on the order of the element.

Comment: could you please show me how

Comment: How to do the first sentence of my answer, or the second? If you don't yet understand how to calculate multiples of the given element in the given group, then you should put this problem aside until you've mastered that more fundamental idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of an element $E$ is the least positive integer $n$ such that $nE=0$. So we’re looking for the least $n$ such that $n(1,1)$ gets sent to zero, that is the least $n$ such that $(n,n)$ is in the kernel $N$. Thus we have the equation $3n+5n \equiv 0$ mod $30$, solving this we want the least $n$ such that $8n$ is a multiple of $30$. By unique factorization, we know that for $8n$ to be a multiple of $30$, n must have $15$ as a factor. Trying $n=15$ solves our equation so our least solution is $n=15$.

Answer (score 1):

First off, note that $30 \cdot ((1,1) + N) = (30,30) + N$. Now, $3\cdot 30 + 5\cdot 30 = 8\cdot 30 \equiv 0 \text{ mod } 30$, so $(30,30) \in N$ which tells us $30 \cdot ((1,1) + N) = N$.

So $(1,1) + N$ has order at most $30$, but remember that if $k\cdot g = 0$ in any group, then this means that the order of the element $g$ divides $k$. Thus, the only possible orders for $(1,1) + N$ are the divisors of $30$.

Then you can start multiplying  $(1,1) + N$ by the divisors of $30$. Which will give you zero?

Answer (score 0):

The "n-th power" of that coset in the quotient is $(n,n)+N$. Now, $(n,n)+N=N$ iff $8n \equiv 0 \pmod {30}$. The *least* value of $n$ fulfilling this equation is $15$.